# Specify which field (in a row) to insert data into

Tags: python, sqlite, conditional-statements, overwrite

I am working on a Python quiz project in which the user answers a series of 10 mathematical questions. Their score/10 is stored in a SQLite database, in a row, along with their name.

I want to make it so that the row with their name can store that particular users **last 5 scores**, rather than 1 score.

I already have the score1 - score5 columns present with the table, but I am unsure how to specify which field the data should be added to.

I suspected it might be done with some sort of if statement:

```
If name is in RESULTS_TABLE;
    If score2 IS NULL
        Insert score into score2
    Elif score3 IS NULL
        Insert score into score3
    Elif score4 IS NULL
        Insert score into score4
    Elif score5 IS NULL
        Insert score into score5
    Else
        Overwrite score into score1
Else
    Insert into RESULTS_TABLE, name, class, score1
```

Obviously this pseudo-code isn't correct as SQLite doesn't have an 'if statement'. How would I go about coding this into my Python program so that the last 5 scores can be stored in my SQLite database?

Comment: If you  keep the  scores in order, you just need to remove the oldest and put the latest at the front moving the others down one

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Thanks for your response. How would I go about doing that? Could you please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Python does have an `if` statement.